# do_shortcode() outside loop not working

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to use a the function do_shortcode() outside the loop of Wordpress. 
I required wp-load.php and shortcodes.php on top of the file, but when i use `do_shortcode('[converter']);` the function only outputs the text `[converter]`, not the function of the shortcode.

Does anyone know how to make the shortcode work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use like this if your shortcode does not have error then its works <?php echo do_shortcode('[converter']'); ?>

Comment: I was echoing the function, after a while i found out that the problem was that i only required wp-load.php, the solution was to require following instead:

`define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );        
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-config.php');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp-load.php wasn't the right file to require, the solution was to require the following:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );        
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-config.php');
```